# How do I sign out users in Firebase 3.0?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth), I force a user to sign out with the method `signOut()`.

This is what I have tried:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
var loggedInUser = firebase.auth();

1. firebase.signOut(); 
2. loggedInUser.signOut(); 
3. rootRef.signOut();
4. signOut();
5. firebase.auth.signOut();
```

I get `... is not a function` for every one of the five above. I know there is no issue with my reference to the new Firebase, since `firebase.database().ref();` and `firebase.auth();` does not throw error. I have also migrated the app in the console.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In JavaScript you can sign out the user with:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  console.log('Signed Out');
}, function(error) {
  console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
});
```

Comment: how can we do this in Java?

Comment: I am doing this and I log 'Signed Out' in the console, but my firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() immediately returns with the user still signed in :(  Using JS SDK 3.5.2

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen What are the cases in which a signOut() might fail?

Comment: I was refreshing the page after calling signOut(). Adding signOut().then(() => { refresh } solved the problem

Answer (score 12):

```
firebase.auth().signOut()
```

simply it works for me!

Answer (score 4):

There have several way to sign out user:

**1. FirebaseUI:** [Refarence](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md)

*Add depenencies:*

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
}
```

Then:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**2. Kotlin:** [Referance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

*Use Android default Authentication dependency, ex:* `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1`

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

---

**3. Default with java:**

*Use Android default Authentication dependency, ex:* `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1`

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null){
    mAuth.signOut();
    Toast.makeText(this, user.getEmail()+ " Sign out!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "You aren't login Yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: That Kotlin code looks awfully similar to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Extending the answer of @Frank van Puffelen, this code works like a charm, but promise rejection handling inside `then()` function as a second parameter is a bad practice.

Rather add a `.catch(e)` block.

Because, if error happens at `signout()` function then would be handled but if error happens at `.then()` block then it wont be handled.

Better code would be,

```
firebase.auth().signOut()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Signed Out');
})
.catch(e=>{
 console.error('Sign Out Error', e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for the latest firebase. It works for my angular firebase authentication.

```
async logout() {
 await signOut(this.auth);
 localStorage.removeItem("user");
}
```

Comment: async and await bring sanity to this function call.  thanks @Muhd

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I correctly understood, but if you want to sign out every user signed in:
That's not possible since the code is running **on the client** and the auth state refers to the client running it.

You can't access every client connected to the firebase auth service since it would mean running code on the server side.

However there's an option to specify the duration of a session, which is the **remember** parameter in the auth section.

Comment: No, just the user currently signed in in the client

Comment: Okay my bad, didn't quite understood the second part of your question.