# How to make Google sign in or sign out buttons change depending on state

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, oauth, frontend

I am a student developing a website that authorizes users using Google sign in. To make the Google sign in or sign out buttons I have a `div` that looks like this:

```
<div id="login_div">

</div>
```

I am trying to make it such that this div will display either a sign in or sign out button depending on if the user is signed in. Using Javascript, how do I create a function `update_login_btns` that will change the inner HTML of the `login_div` to either the sign in or sign out button and can be called on all three of the following occasions:

- When the window loads (check if user signed in or not and display correct button)
- When the user signs in (change inner HTML of div to sign out)
- When the user signs out (change inner HTML of div to sign in)

I have looked at Stack Overflow and some Google docs but can't seem to find out how exactly to make this happen.

Comment: You can just check for the state of the user and change the text and the `onclick` attribute of the `<button>`  accordingly, you don't need to replace with `innerHTML` for that.

Answer (score 0):

the best ways to checke authorizes users using Google sign in is to using firebase 
in the firebase    There are many  methode provide you to check use sign in or sign out 
so  , i suggestion to  you to  visite the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs) of firebase

after that : 
you can check this post 
[How do I sign out users in Firebase 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376708/how-do-i-sign-out-users-in-firebase-3-0)

she could help you